# Is there a way for me to create role based access after successfully login in angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want that when one logs in it check for the admin type then redirect him to the specific component for examp HOD should acces the admidashboard cict should access admin2 dashboard, etc.

*Here is my mongoose schema*

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const ClearAdminSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email:
    {
        type:String,
        required:true,
        trim:true
    },
    password:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    name:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        trim:true

    },
    admintype:{
        type:String,
        type:String,
        enum :['HOD','CICT','Sports','SUASAB','Admin']
    },
    university:{
        type:String,
        default:"Sokoine University of Agriculture"
    },
    college:{
       type:String,
       required:true
    },
    department:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    }
});

const ClearAdmin = mongoose.model('ClearAdmin', ClearAdminSchema);
module.exports = ClearAdmin;
```

*Here is my auth.guard.ts*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Router } from '@angular/router'


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {


  constructor(private auth: AuthService,private router:Router, private user: UserService)
  {

  }


  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {

      if(this.auth.isLoggedIn)
      {
        return true
      }
    return this.user.isLoggedIn().pipe(map(res => { 
       if(res.status)
       {
         this.auth.setLoggedIn(true)
         return true
       }
       else
       {
         this.router.navigate(['login'])
         return false
       }


      }))


    }

}
```

*Here is my auth.service.ts*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import{ HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

interface myData
{
  success:boolean,
  message: string,
  token:"user_token"
  admintype:String
}
interface moData
{
  success:boolean,
  message:String

}


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  uri : String = 'http://localhost:4000';

  private loggedInStatus = false
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  setLoggedIn(value: boolean)
  {
  this.loggedInStatus = value
  }

  get isLoggedIn()
  {
    return this.loggedInStatus
  }


  getUserDetails(email: String,password:String){

    //post these details to the database
    return this.http.post<myData>(`${this.uri}/auth`,{ email,password});
  }

  signupadminsections(email:String,password:String,name:String, 
      admintype:String,college:String,department:String)
  {
    //add new admin section
    return this.http.post<moData>(`${this.uri}/register`,{ email,password,name,admintype,college,department});
  }
}
```

*Here is my Login.component.ts*

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private Auth: AuthService,private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  loginUser(event)
  {
    event.preventDefault()
    const target = event.target
    const email= target.querySelector('#email').value
    const password = target.querySelector('#password').value


    this.Auth.getUserDetails(email, password).subscribe(data => { 
      if(data.token)
      {
        localStorage.setItem('user_token',data.token);
        //redirect the person to admin page
        this.router.navigate(['admin'])
        this.Auth.setLoggedIn(true)


      }
      else
      {

        window.alert(data.message);
      }

    });
    console.log(email, password)
  }

  logoutUser()
{

  localStorage.removeItem('user_token');
  this.router.navigate(['login'])
  this.Auth.setLoggedIn(false);
  console.log(event);

}
}
```

I want that when one logs in it check for the admin type then redirect him to the specific component for examp HOD should acces the admidashboard cict should access admin2 dashboard, etc.

*This is my Roleguard.ts*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RoleGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor( public auth: AuthService) {}
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {


    return true;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-permissions

This package is very good for role based permission, You can set condition on `routing level`, `component level` or on individual element as well.

Can useable in template like below -

```
<ng-template ngxPermissionsOnly="ADMIN">
  <div>You can see this text congrats</div>
 </ng-template>
```

Compatible with all version of Angular (v2+)

Comment: what if am not using angular material just normal css will it work for me @Pardeep

Comment: There is no relation of angular material or css with this package.

Comment: i tried but i could get a clear tutorial on role base redirecting

Comment: @KyleMutta could you please mention url of that tutorial?

Comment: hellow could you complete the code and tell me how i can achieve that i couldnt find any helping tutorials @dasunse

Comment: @dasunse I have the roleguard.ts see what am missing

Answer (score 0):

I recommond to use an canActivate RoleGuardService.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { Router, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RoleGuardService {
    constructor(public auth: AuthService) {}
    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
        // Here only return true if only user have that permission or have that role
        // Otherwise return false
        // You can read data route.data.expectedRoles
        return true;
    }
}
```

In your app.routes.ts

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
{
    path: 'dashboard',
    canActivate: [RoleGuardService],
    data: {
      expectedRoles: ['Admin', 'HOD']
    }     
}
```

By this mechanism it prevents route changing if user doesn't have that access(Role or Permission)

And in your  components also you can easily use this way

```
<div *ngIf="*** an condition to check your logged user have a role or privillage  ***">

</div>
```

It is better to user have role with set of permissions

Comment: thanks brother but i want it to check for the rolle and give acces meaning that it should check on the database and indentfy the role and give acces to the respective role forexample an HOD sould acces only admin page

Comment: How to do i access expected roles